# Unix command to add user to AllowUsers list for SSH access?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ssh, sshd

I understand that to allow a web user access to SSH, I have to open up /etc/ssh/sshd_config and manually add each username to the list and restart sshd.

I built a small custom bash script to create users, do other setup, etc. Is there a command to add each user to the AllowUsers list in sshd_config? This would be extremely helpful vs doing it manually all the time. Or if I delete a user, have it removed from the list automatically?

Comment: Might be a question for [unix.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You may have to ensure user could log in for command line:

   ```
   getent passwd $USER
   usertoto:x:1234:1234:User Toto,,,:/home/usertoto/:/bin/false
   ```

   The last field is the shell to start, ``false'' will not let *`usertoto`* open any command line terminal.

   This could changed by

   ```
   chsh -s /bin/sh usertoto
   ```
2. Using a group instead of a list of user

   You could create a group, allowed to log in, than add users into this group. This could by simplier than edit manually user list into sshd config.

   See *`AllowGroups`* in `man sshd_config` and `man adduser`

   ```
   adduser usertoto sshallowed
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Useful command: sed -i -e 's/AllowUsers \(.*\)/\0 the-user/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: @Federico Thanks. Typo: Remove the parenthesis around the .*